# SQL Server Full-Text Index with Overridable Data

Tags: sql-server, indexing, full-text-search

I am trying to work with SQL Server full-text indexes, but have a very unique scenario and am hitting a snag. For the system we are building, we have a main table called `Equipment` that has some general columns: DisplayName, ModelNumber, Overview, Description, etc. and creating a full-text index on this is pretty basic. The full structure of this table is:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Equipment](
    [Id] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,       
    [CategoryId] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [DistributorId] [bigint] NULL,
    [DistrbutorLocationId] [bigint] NULL,
    [ManufacturerId] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [PrimaryImageId]  AS ([dbo].[fn_GetPrimaryImage]([Id])),
    [Condition] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [DisplayName] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL,
    [ModelNumber] [nvarchar](75) NOT NULL,
    [Overview] [nvarchar](1024) NULL,
    [Description] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [CurrentPrice]  AS (coalesce([SalePrice],[SuggestedPrice])),
    [SalePrice] [money] NULL,
    [SuggestedPrice] [money] NOT NULL,
    [Warranty] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [IsActive] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [IsPublished] [bit] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Equipment] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
)
```

The problem I have is users can override certain fields - solely for their "version" of an `Equipment` entity - with overrides stored in a separate table. For example, they can override `DisplayName`, but that's the only property/field they override - everything else would be the original values. They can then toggle these overrides on/off in case they temporarily override it, but then want to fall back to the default/original value. The structure of the overrides table is:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[EquipmentOverride](
    [Id] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,       
    [DistributorId] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [EquipmentId] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [EquipmentKey] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [Value] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [IsActive] [bit] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_EquipmentOverride] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
)
```

So, individual equipment records can be added to the main table, but if a distributor wanted to override the `DisplayName` property, they would ultimately add a record to the `EquipmentOverride` table with a corresponding `EquipmentId`, `EquipmentKey` of 0 (correlates to `DisplayName` - these are all enums within a C# app) and their `DistributorId`. When pulling individual equipment records, I do a `COALESCE(dbo.fn_GetDistributorEquipmentValue(@DistributorId, Equipment.Id, 0), Equipment.DisplayName)` which gets me either the overridden value or falls back to the default value for an individual distributor. The structure of `dbo.fn_GetDistributorEquipmentValue` just looks at the `EquipmentOverride` table to see if one exists:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_GetDistributorEquipmentValue] 
(
    @DistributorId bigint,
    @EquipmentId bigint,
    @Key tinyint
)
RETURNS nvarchar(max)
AS
BEGIN
    
    RETURN (SELECT [Value]
            FROM EquipmentOverride
            WHERE DistributorId = @DistributorId AND
                  EquipmentId = @EquipmentId AND
                  EquipmentKey = @Key AND
                  IsActive = 1);

END
```

My main problem with this is trying to create a full-text index that is distributor-specific, since querying needs to include any overrides they may have done. The best solution I can come up with is a full-text catalog per distributor that is then queryable, but that feels very wrong and seems like a bad idea from a performance perspective - especially since the values are so dynamic that any queries would have to rebuild it for that distributor each time.

Has anyone run into a scenario like this where you need a dynamic full-text index? I did try utilizing `LIKE` operators, but if the description in a record says something like 'STIHL RMA 460' and someone searches for `stihl 460`, the results are null. Using `CONTAINS` here would work, but it doesn't include the override values so I'm back at square one. I tried to create a view that includes everything, but since that can't have a unique index (since overrides correlate back to individual `Equipment` records), SQL wouldn't let me create it.

Comment: You should've mirrored the whole table when doing overrides, it would have simplified your code, instead of mixing in Key/value stuff

Comment: That's the only other option I could come up with!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply add the `EquipmentOverride` table to the full-text index, then filter it by `DistributorID` when you query it.

This is going to be somewhat easier to do without functions. Just left-join it and filter it in the `ON`

```sql
SELECT
  e.*,
  ISNULL(eo.DisplayName, e.DisplayName) AS OverridenDisplayName
FROM Equipment e
LEFT JOIN EquipmentOverride eo
  ON eo.DistributorId = @DistributorId
 AND eo.EquipmentId = e.Id
 AND eo.EquipmentKey = 0
 AND eo.IsActive = 1
WHERE eo.DisplayName IS NULL AND CONTAINS(e.Value, @search)
   OR CONTAINS(eo.Value, @search);
```

In some instances it may be faster to query `CONTAINSTABLE` instead.

If you want to query across many fields and you want all the overrides then you could search inside a subquery.

```sql
SELECT
  e.*,
  ISNULL(eo.DisplayName, e.DisplayName) AS OverridenDisplayName,
  ISNULL(eo.ModelNumber, e.ModelNumber) AS OverridenModelNumber
FROM Equipment e
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT
      MIN(CASE WHEN eo.EquipmentKey = 0 THEN e.Value END) AS DisplayName,
      MIN(CASE WHEN eo.EquipmentKey = 1 THEN e.Value END) AS ModelNumber,
      MIN(CASE WHEN CONTAINS(e.Value, @search) THEN 1 END) DoesContain
    FROM EquipmentOverride eo
    WHERE eo.DistributorId = @DistributorId
      AND eo.EquipmentId = e.Id
      AND eo.EquipmentKey in (0, 1)
      AND eo.IsActive = 1
) eo
WHERE eo.DisplayName IS NULL AND CONTAINS(e.Value, @search)
   OR eo.DoesContain = 1;
```

Comment: The problem with this is there are 7 fields that can be overridden. Would I join the table for each override option to grab the corresponding values for each column?

Comment: isn't that how you have to do now?

Comment: That's where the function comes in - it takes the joins out, though I suppose fundamentally that is what it's doing. Hadn't thought of it like that, so I'll give this a try  thank you!

Comment: See edits. Scalar functions are notoriously bad for performance, joins generally perform much better. You can use an *inline* (not multi-statement) Table Function, which performs well usually.

Comment: @Charlieface that's a creative update! How would this be full-text indexable by distributor though?

Comment: It's not. Full-text indexes don't work like that. But if the search term is sufficiently narrow then I wouldn't think it would be a perf problem (more than a regular full-text search which is anyway slow)